# How do i echo selected options from a loop of questions with php

Tags: php, html

I have this loop that echo questions from database into a form with predetermined answers in select option like Yes, No, Not sure. User can answer any amount of question except that at least one question must be answered. How do i echo the question(s) and corresponding selected answer back to the user on submitting the form.

Here i retrieve the questions from dbase

```
<form method="post" action="">
<?php         
    $sql = 'SELECT starttime, country,league, home, away,gamecode 
    FROM games 
    WHERE starttime > DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),"%d/%m/%y %H:%i") 
    ORDER BY starttime' ;
    $retval = mysql_query($sql);
    if(! $retval )
    {
      die('Could not get games for the date selected: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
```

Here i echo the question to the user

```
 echo "{$row['country']} | {$row['league']} | Time:{$row['starttime']}  <br> ". 
  "<div align='center'><span class='style3'>{$row['home']} VS ".
         "{$row['away']} <br> ".
```

Here, i echo predetermined selectable answers for each of the above question

EDITED
//My form head is somewhere above the sql query

```
     "<select name='gm" . $row['gamecode'] ."' >
         <option value=''>Select option</option>
    <option value='btsyes'>BTS (YES)</option>
    <option value='btsno'>BTS (NO)</option>
    <option value='over2.5'>Over2.5(Total Goals)</option>
    <option value='under2.5'>Under 2.5(Total Goals)</option>
    <option value='oddtg'>Odd(Total Goals)</option>
    <option value='eventg'>Even(Total Goals)</option>
    </select></span></div>".
             "<hr>";
    } 

?>



 <input type="submit" name="play" value="Register Bet" />
    </form></div>
```

All the above works fine but here i want to echo the question and the answer selected back to the user for confirmation

this is what i try

```
 if (isset($_POST ['play'])){
echo "Confirm Your Selection </br>";
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value ) {
  if($value !=''){   

      echo $key."-".$value;
           echo "<br>";
     }else{ echo "No valid selection Made <br>";}
    }
}
```

I now use developers tool and on the network tab, i dont know what exacly to focus on.
This is what i get if user selects fist two options                     Confirm Your Selection 
1
2
No valid selection Made 
No valid selection Made 
No valid selection Made 
Register Bet

Comment: I took your select tag and tested it. It shows up correctly. Make sure your html is correct. Also, are you checking developer tools on your browser? check the request body to see what you're sending in the first place. Let me know your findings.

Comment: Thanks. the select tag works fine. It displays the intended questions and all 7 options in the drop down select option menu but the problem here is to echo which option the user selected for all the loops once the form is submitted.

Comment: Sorry, not getting the picture. Could you please add more information. So you have a form with multiple questions and answers? or one form for each question and multiple forms on the page? Let me know it might be just an issue with your design.

Comment: from $sql above, i retrieve some questions from the database. From echo above, i display the questions retrieved to the user. Each question now has a drop down select option. All in just one form.  The problem is that, once the user is done selecting options for each question, I want to echo the question and the option selected (answer) back to the screen for user to confirm

Comment: that's the issue I think. you have multiple selects in one form with the same name. when you submit your form you get only one value gm=so.
for each question make unique select name that way you will get values for each answer

Comment: I use a while loop to reproduce the Select option drop down. (i.e from the while loop above to the </hr> How do i make the name unique for each loop of the select option?     -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<select name= 'gm[]'>
         <option value='so'>select option</option>
<option value='btsyes'>BTS (YES)</option>
<option value='btsno'>BTS (NO)</option>
<option value='over2.5'>Over2.5(Total Goals)</option>
<option value='under2.5'>Under 2.5(Total Goals)</option>
<option value='oddtg'>Odd(Total Goals)</option>
<option value='eventg'>Even(Total Goals)</option>
</select>
```

By Doing gm[] you are saying that this values is an array. with that you can have multiple values set under $_POST['gm']

**Additional**

your form will send all selects by default, if default value is not provided then first value will be selected and transferred. To avoid that, just do as you did when checking if `value != ''`

```
<select name="gm"><option value=''>Choose your Answer</option></select>
```

If user does not select '' empty field will be passed, and you could skip it.

**EDIT #2 Working Copy**

```
<form action="" method="POST">

<select name='gm[firstQuestion]'>
    <option value=''>Select Please</option>
    <option value='Foo'>Foo</option>
    <option value='Bar'>Bar</option>
    <option value='Zoo'>Zoo</option>
    <option vlaue='Park'>Park</option>
</select>
<br>
<select name='gm[secondQuestion]'>
    <option value=''>Select Please</option>
    <option value='Foo'>Foo</option>
    <option value='Bar'>Bar</option>
    <option value='Zoo'>Zoo</option>
    <option vlaue='Park'>Park</option>
</select>
<br>
<select name='gm[thidQuestion]'>
    <option value=''>Select Please</option>
    <option value='Foo'>Foo</option>
    <option value='Bar'>Bar</option>
    <option value='Zoo'>Zoo</option>
    <option vlaue='Park'>Park</option>
</select>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="answer">
```

Constructing this form with this PHP code

```
foreach($_POST['gm'] as $key => $answer){
    if($answer != ''){
        echo "your Question #" . $key . ' Answer is ' . $answer . PHP_EOL;
    }

}
```

Check the output

Comment: using 'gm[]' all the select option got the same name 'gm[]'. i tried the second suggestion <select name= 'gm". $row['gamecode'] ."'>. //($row['gamecode'] being a 4digit unique number retrieved from dbase.). So with the second suggestion, all select option got different names like gm1223, gm3726, gm7464 etc. So while trying to echo what user submitted, i used if(isset($_POST ['gm". $row['gamecode'] ."']) { echo $_POST ['gm". $row['gamecode'] ."'];} which brings error around $_POST ['gm". $row['gamecode'] ."']. How do i display each selection made from each select option.

Comment: It returns error. Notice: Undefined variable: row in C:\xampp\htdocs\gumo\yesno.php on line 19
Notice: Undefined index: in C:\xampp\htdocs\gumo\yesno.php on line 19. I tried to work around it using a for each loop like this. foreach ($_POST as $key => $value ) {
  if($value !=''){    
        echo $key."-".$value; What i get is a list of both selected and unselected options. I only want a list of selected options.

Comment: It did work like gm1234 => selectValue; But it keep returning unselected values. Here is the code i use in posting the values. if (isset($_POST ['play'])){
echo "Confirm Your Selection </br>";
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value ) {
  if($value !=''){    
        echo $key."-".$value;
           echo "<br>";
     }else{ echo "No valid selection Made <br>";}
    }
}. After it echos gm1234 => selectValue it echos No valid selection made. for other unselected options in the loop

Comment: so user can avoid answering some questions and you don't want to include those right? in this case you have to have default value in select
look at the edit

Comment: all options provided are form based assuming this is the fastest way to implement. In addition, this can be achieved using javascript easily.

Comment: I have empty value in the first option. but i still get "No valid selection made. for other unselected options" in the loop

Comment: please edit your question with 'I have empty value in the first option'. I still see that default value is 'so'. Also, please confirm that you've double checked values you are sending in with 'inspect element -> network tab'

Comment: answer has been edited. please check out the code and test it. This is a combination of using gm[] and unique identifier.